# Ridiculously huge margin-top with percentage value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, margin

Last time I poorly expressed my problem and I was misunderstood. So I got that iframe on my website and I need to use % value between the title and content (placeholders here for now) but using percentage values on margin-top makes it too big, 100% value is something about 1900px! Just take a look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyfLQ.jpg or just check my website: http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/ (click the gear icon). How can I force margin-top of #portNav to base on actual height of the iframe (which is based on users screen resolution)?

Code of the iframe:

```
body 
{
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
margin: 0 0 0 0;
height:100%;
max-height:600px;
max-width:900px;
}

#container
{
margin-top:-12px;
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#portNav
{
margin-top:30%;
}

#title
{
width:100%;
height:0.42%;
}

#content
{
width:70%;
clear:both;
margin-top:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
}

<div id="container">
<div id="title">
    <h1>My portfolio</h1>
</div>

<div id="portNav" style="overflow:hidden;">
 <ul class="navi">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="navi" src="../images/placeholder01_out.png" alt="1" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="navi" src="../images/placeholder02_out.png" alt="1" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#"><img class="navi" src="../images/placeholder03_out.png" alt="1" /></a>
    </li>
 </ul>     
</div>
<a href="#" id="right-button">DALEJ!</a>
```

Comment: I am understanding correctly that currently the percentages are a percentage of the overall page they are on and you instead want them to be percentages of the size of the iframe itself?

Comment: Your website fails to load for me.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that the percentages are from the overall page, because I tested it opening iframes source html itself and it was the same. So I guess it's based on the size of the iframe, but its height is 1900px (that's what google chrome tells me). Even setting body max-height doesn't help at all.

Comment: @j08691 I dunno why for some people it doesn't load, maybe try direct link http://klaunfizia.pl/damian/index.html I've put the code on jsfiddle for those, who can't open my website, the results are the same: http://jsfiddle.net/75PcB/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is related or not and this is an old question but...margin-top when used with a percentage sets the top margin to a percentage of the WIDTH of the container.  That means 100% would be 100% of the WIDTH of whatever container it is within...not height.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage `100%` is a way to get the height of the `document` so that's why it returns a huge `margin-top`. Percentage values are mostly used when making responsive layouts because they change the values according to what the document's height is at a moment. So you may use pixel values to give a fixed `margin-top` or use a less percentage value like `2%` or `3%` or something else that fits your design.

As per your needs, to set the `margin-top` as the actual frame size you need to use Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried limiting documents height and it didn't make a difference. How can I make margin-top based on the actual iframe size? Because setting it on 2-3% won't make much difference between small and big screens.

Comment: @user2660811 for that you may use Javascript to get the height of the iframe and set that as the margin-top.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't that look strange for you? If I set margin-top:100% and check it with Google Chrome View Elements it says, that the margin is set to 1900px! And no matter how big is the window, my native resolution is 1080 so it's ~half of this value.

Comment: Then somewhere else in your CSS there's a problem.

Comment: That's why I've come here. I tried many ideas but none helped, I tried to keep the code as basic as possible but no results.